# How to show numbers above the letters on iPad Keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I want to show Numbers and letters at same time in Keyboard on iPad, where Numbers Row Should shows on top of Letters in keyboard for default keyboard type for textfield.

[image]

I tried using all different types of keyboard types but it doesn't match the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

**Only iPad Pro 12.9” models can enable number row for the keyboard by default. No other iPad lineup can.**

If user want the number pad on top of alpha digits, it can be possible in **two ways** :

1. **Turning ON the Flick Key Option****:

- Bring up the iPad's keyboard (alphanumeric-Normal keyboard)
- To enter the "flick" symbol (grey colored symbols or numbers), touch a key and then pull downwards.
- As you pull down, the symbol will replace the
  letter on the keyboard and it'll be entered into the text field.

Make sure "**Enable Key Flick**" is **Enable** in Settings:

- Open the Settings app. Tap "General."
- Select the "Keyboard"
- Toggle ON "Enable Key Flicks ."

2. Using **third party keyboards** such as **SwiftKey**
   https://www.guidingtech.com/best-iphone-keyboards-numbers-row-on-top/